# Arabic letter not aligned properly

Tags: xetex, arabic, letters, newlfm

I am trying to write an official letter in Arabic using the package `newlfm` but the text is aligned from left to right instead of right to left. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,stdletter,orderfromtodate,sigcenter]{newlfm}
\newlfmP{headermarginsize=20pt}
\newlfmP{addrfromskipbefore=0pt}
\newlfmP{addrtoskipbefore=-25pt}
\newlfmP{dateskipbefore=0pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=0pt}
\newlfmP{sigskipbefore=30pt}
% 
\newlfmP{Headlinewd=0pt,Footlinewd=0pt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@zfancyhead}{\fancy@reset}{\f@nch@reset}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@nch@olh}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@nch@olh}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyorh}{\f@nch@orh}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[calendar=gregorian,hijricorrection=1,locale=morocco]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\setmainfont{Amiri}

\namefrom{سعيد}
\addrfrom{%
\\193 الصويرة 44000
\\الهاتف: \LR{\textenglish{06~00~00~00~00}}
}

\addrto{%
\textbf{إلى السيد: المدير بالنيابة للمدرسة العليا للتكنولوجيا بالناظور}\\     
}

\dateset{\today}

\greetto{الموضوع: شغل منصب أستاذ التعليم العالي مساعد}

\closeline{التوقيع:}

\begin{document}

\begin{newlfm}

\end{newlfm}

\end{document}
```

And below is the resulting document:

[image]

I would appreciate it if someone can help me fix the alignment (make it right to left instead of left to right). Thanks.

Comment: The letter construction doesn't allow for this being set right-to-left. You're better of not using [`newlfm`](//ctan.org/pkg/newlfm).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `letter` document class with the `layout=sectioning` option of `babel`, instead of `newlfm`

You might be able to adapt this template, which requires LuaLaTeX 1.12 or later.  (It would work in XeLaTeX, with a few changes.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.tabular, british]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX,
                      Renderer=HarfBuzz }

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0, Ligatures=Common, Language=Default]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures=Common, Language=Default]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont{tt}
          [Language=Default]{Libertinus Mono}

\babelprovide[import=ar-MA, main]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}
          {Amiri}
% Set \babelfont[arabic]{sf} here if needed.
\babelfont[arabic]{tt}
          {ALM Fixed}

\babeltags{english=british}

\signature{سعيد}

\address{
  {193 الصويرة 44000}\\
  {الهاتف:}\\
  \textenglish{06~00~00~00~00}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{\textbf{إلى السيد: المدير بالنيابة للمدرسة العليا للتكنولوجيا بالناظور}}
\opening{الموضوع: شغل منصب أستاذ التعليم العالي مساعد}

\ldots

\closing{التوقيع:}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: Amiri sample]

I attempted to simply copy and paste the Arabic from the question, and apologize for any errors.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I used the letter class for many letters before, but the results with the newlfm class look much better for some letters I wrote in english, and that's why I wanted to use newlfm for arabic letters.